# How to make a grid that dynamically resizes in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a grid that I have made in sprite kit for my game.  The grid is made with SKSpritenodes that are images.  I want to have levels of difficulty where the grid is 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, and 6x6. Each image is approximately a static 100 in width and height. When my grid is 2x2 the grid looks good centered in the middle, However, it looks too small and does not take up a lot of screen space.  When the grid is 3x3, it does not look good when centered and looks slightly too small.  When the grid is 4x4, it looks good centered, however, also looks slightly too small for the screen. When the grid is 5x5, it looks off when centered, but looks good for the screen.  When the grid is 6x6, it looks great and proportionate.  My question is, how can I made all the grid sizes look when centered and take up the appropriate amount of screen space.  Meaning, I want the 2x2 to have larger grid squares than the 3x3, and the 3x3 to have larger grid squares than the 4x4 and so on and so forth.  I want to have a grid that dynamically resizes based on the given rows and columns.

Comment: The beauty of sprite kit is we have scaling given to us automatically.  Just make your scene size the size of the parent node holding your squares, and it will scale for you (you may want to include padding for  different aspect ratios)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon how does this work? How do you make a set of squares so they scale to their parent, in an automagical manner? I have a set of simple maths making divisions for placing things evenly across the screen, and use a calculation of the total screen size to determine how big to make my buttons. It took me forever to figure out and build, and I thought this was the only way to do it. Feeling extra special stupid if there's an automagical way to do this in SpriteKit.

Comment: @Confused, let's say 1 square is 10x10.  this means a 2x2 square is 20x20.  If I set the scene size to 20x20, sprite kit will fill up the screen so that the the 20x20 scene fills up the the screen.  Of course, since 20x20 is not a 16 by 9 ratio,  we will get stuff cut off.  So we make the scene size 36x20 to keep it in a 16:9 format

Comment: And then you scale the scene?

Comment: you scale nothing,  this is why scaleMode exists.  It does the scaling for us

Comment: I'm missing something. The screen isn't anything like 36x20. So how do you get from your representative values to something pertinent to the actual screen size?

Comment: This is all done behind the scenes. Make a new project, go into your SKS file, and make the scene size 9x16,  then put in a red box with the size 9x16

Comment: I work in SKS screen sizes accurate in the points sense, so 1024x768 for an iPad, because all my artwork is based on these numbers, both in terms of positions and sizes. So using arbitrary, representative values/numbers for the sake of one scaling operation messes up everything. Are you saying "use these small numbers because they're easier to think in"?

Comment: and where is this wondrous scaleMode you speak of. I've never come across this.

Comment: I dont know what you are doing, I am talking about in terms of @Keyshawn's question here

Comment: it is a part of every scene, check the view controller

Comment: But what you're suggesting isolates to ONLY this problem. This isn't going to be the only problem he has when laying out his level button images. He's also going to (likely) have labels and options buttons, perhaps a back button, and other artwork that's at more screen sensitive and specific sizes.

Comment: argh, I see. It's .aspectFill that's magical. It takes whatever is talked about and ramps it up to fill the screen. So I think I've got it, you are suggesting these small numbers to make it cognitively lighter to think about the filling of the screen with buttons in any given grid layout. That's fine for the simplest of isolated problems. And makes a good start for thinking about how to space things out, but it doesn't leave much room for fudging in spaces between buttons, nor for other artwork and buttons common to a level selection screen.

Comment: that is a different problem entirely that could be handled in a variety of ways (Use 2 SKViews, etc)

Comment: Use 2 SKViews at the same time, on the screen at once? Is this even possible?

Comment: the OP could also just scale the grid via a parent node  to match the scene size,  I was just commenting 1 solution, not answering

Comment: you seen it with my split screen question

Comment: That's two SKViews side by side. SplitScreen. That's not going to solve the problem of incorporating a background, options buttons, a start button, a back button, these level buttons and whatever else he wants to show at this point, in this menu.

Comment: you can overlay them as well

Comment: Well, I don't believe that the aspect fill would work KnightOfDragon.  I have a grid in my game, say for example like a match three game.  Each square is 100 in width and height. 6 x 6 at 100 width and height look good. However, at 2 x 2 at 100 width and height does not look good, it is too small.  So, I need the squares in the 2 x 2 to be larger than if I had a level that was 6 x 6 @KnightOfDragon.